# Multiple types of tokens for ADFS

Tags: adfs3.0, adfs4.0

I'm trying to find out if it is possible for ADFS to send two types of tokens on one authentication ?

We have external systems working with JWT tokens but also systems with SAML tokens.  We like to receive a JWT token and SAML token as a response on one authentication request to ADFS.

I was reading up on the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks but this seems to be consecutive means of authentication not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it's either one or the other.

It's not an ADFS issue.

That behaviour is proscribed by the protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, as this is not my field of expertise it was hard to find any information on google